# Question on homeomorphism ..

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> **Problem**Show that the subspace $(a,b)$  of $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic with $(0,1)$ and the subspace $[a,b]$ of  $\mathbb{R}$ is  homeomorphic with $[0,1]$.

> **attempt** suppose $f:(a,b)\to (0,1)$ defined by $f(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$. It is easy to show that $f$ is bijective. How to prove that $f$ is continuous by $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that a continuous function minus a constant is again a continuous function?

Comment: Your question is missing some important context. Is it safe to presume that you know the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity? If so, did you attempt to apply that definition to the function $f$? And if so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Do you know how to prove that $g(x) = {\alpha}x + {\beta}$ is continuous?

Comment: @Joseph Let $x_1,x_2\in \mathbb{R}$ then $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=|\frac{x_1-a}{b-a}-\frac{x_2-a}{b-a}|$ Proceed like this and use simply $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

Comment: @Dave Actually, Actually I forgot the method. Thanks. Now I can solve.

Comment: @Aman , Thanks${}$

Answer (score 2):

$f$, and its inverse too, are of the form $f(x)=\alpha x + \beta$ ($\alpha >0, \beta \in \Bbb R$) and such a map is Lipschitz: $$|f(x)-f(y)| \le \alpha |x-y|$$ and this implies that both are (uniformly) continuous by an easy $\epsilon/\delta$ argument.